# Settings in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm super new in Android Studio. 1) How can I turn on status bar? 2) When I compile and run my app, in `toolbar` I see my app name. Where can I change it and why I can't see this name instantly in  Android Studio? (btw I also can't see 3 dots in the top right corner) Only if I compile my app to `.apk` I can see toolbar name and three dots in the top right corner (settings).

[image: s]

Comment: Where can I see true app design without compiling?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for dislikes guys. If it's easy, just help me. Here's the answer for the first question

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I turn on status bar?

   On default a new project comes with a status bar.
2. Where can I change it?

   To change your name on the status bar you need to go to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

   And change `android:label="@string/app_name"` to whatever name you want